# admin.storage() not working in firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

when I try to access firebase storage via admin SDK in firebase function, it fails on admin.storage(), however succeed on admin.database(), any suggestion?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');  

const serviceAccount = require("./myapp-ea8ed-firebase-adminsdk-140ib-682f0b6fce.json");    

admin.initializeApp({
       credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
       databaseURL: "https://myapp-ea8ed.firebaseio.com"
});
```

in the function I can access the firebase database by

```
const ref = admin.database().ref("/root");
```

but fail on access firebase storage by

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket("myapp-ea8ed.appspot.com");
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem.  What is your code that's failing?  What is the error message?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: What makes you think “it fails”? It's showing an error message? You need to add that to your question.

Comment: admin.storage() returns null.  it works when I run the script from local node.js,  but fails after deployed to firebase functions, however admin.database() always works.